# Fixed Width Master Page Issue: List Item Drop Down Menu Gets Cropped / Cutoff

Tags: master-page, page-layout, css, branding, custom-masterpage

We have a custom master page that is setup in a Fixed Width format. On pages that have a lot of columns we get overflow scroll bars on the x axis which we are fine with.

The issue is that the list item drop down menu seems to get cropped / cutoff / put behind the left fixed width panel.

At first we thought it was a z-index issue. However it seems to be something else. Does anyone know how to get this to overlay on top of the fixed panel.

Comment: Have you found an answer to this yet as I am having the same issue?

Comment: Overflow:hidden?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following string in CSS stylesheet:

```
.ms-headerCellStyleMenuOpen div.ms-core-menu-box{position:fixed !important;}
```

And it worked.